# How to use keras image_dataset_from_directory with custom structures?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow-datasets

Keras `image_dataset_from_directory` inside the `preprocessing` module takes a path as an argument and automatically infers the classes when those images are stored in separate subfolders. In my case, however, I have a single folder and image classes are then specified in a DataFrame.

```
.
├── datasets
│   ├── sample_submit.csv
│   ├── test_images
│   │   ├── test_0000.jpg
│   │   ├── test_0001.jpg
│   │   ├── test_0002.jpg
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── test_images.csv
│   ├── train_images
│   │   ├── train_0000.jpg
│   │   ├── train_0001.jpg
│   │   ├── train_0002.jpg
│   │   └── ...
│   └── train_images.csv
└── model.py
```

Tensorflow's [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory) specifies that when you are not inferring the labels, a list or tuple must be specified, which I get from the DataFrame `df`. However, when I specify the image folder, TensorFlow returns a `ValueError` because it has found no images:

```
In [1]: df = pd.read_csv('datasets/train_images.csv')
   ...: tds = keras.preprocessing\
   ...:    .image_dataset_from_directory('datasets/train_images', list(df['class']),
   ...:                                  validation_split=0.2, subset='training',
   ...:                                  seed=123, image_size(180, 180))

ValueError: Expected the lengths of `labels` to match the number of files in the target directory. len(labels) is 1102 while we found 0 files in datasets/train_images.
```

Why does keras not recognise the images within the folder? I have tried setting the "full" relative path with `./datasets/train_images`, adding a slash with `datasets/train_images/` and also the absolute path, to no avail. What is missing here? Alternatively, is there a more efficient approach in this case where I can still get the train/test split?

---

**EDIT:** It seems there is a limitation with keras and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63906723/9148880) originally laid it out, but remained too vague to get to the heart of the matter.

Plain and clear: **keras seems to always scrape the subfolders of the `directory` argument for images and build the dataset.** The workaround to enable the loading of images is to wrap an additional folder (`outer_train`) and pass it to `directory`.

However, I *still* have problems with this approach, because now keras seems unable to take the custom classes passed as a list and outputs `Found 1102 files belonging to 1 classes.` (in this case, the name of the *now* subfolder `train_images`), so any help is still appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem! Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

> keras seems to always scrape the subfolders of the directory argument for images and build the dataset. The workaround to enable the loading of images is to wrap an additional folder (outer_train) and pass it to directory.

The problem is the `image_dataset_from_directory` method asks a directory which contains other directories and starts getting the images inside the directories present from the directory you gave in input.

> However, I still have problems with this approach, because now keras seems unable to take the custom classes passed as a list and outputs.

I don't think you can read images like that. If you want the method to read the images of a custom class then you have to place the folder with the custom class of images inside the folder you want to read like this:

- directory_to_read/

  - class__1/

    - img1
    - img2
  - class__2/

    - img1
    - img2
  - custom_class/

    - img1
    - img2